# The use of the present perfect and the past parfect in context

Tags: present-perfect, past-perfect

Let's say that I have just experieced a sharp pain and want to say that this is the worst pain by now. Do I say

> I have never experienced such a pain before

or

> I had never experienced such a pain before?

I think that should use the present perfect because the pain have just happened. But my native English speking friend says that either can actually be used. I am curious to know what other native English speakers have to say about that. He also said that if it were yesterday it definetly has to be the past perfect. For example:

> I had a terrible pain yesterday. I had never experieced anything like that before.

Could the present perfect be used in this sentence?

Comment: If you have "just experienced a sharp pain" then the first sentence is correct.The second second is incorrect for that, but would be correct when describing a previous event.

Comment: I think you already know the answer to this. PP **can always** be used after SP. It all depends on what **you want to say**. Also, "I had never experienced such a pain before [that accident which happened at some earlier point in time]*? **implies** something happened first.

Comment: Is my third sentence correct?

Comment: Can the present perfect be used in my third sentence? If not, tell me please why.

Comment: Yes, Yes, Yes. I just told you why. It is preceded by "I ***had*** a terrible pain ***yesterday"***. The past perfect does not have  to be in the same sentence!

Comment: Dmytro is asking if the present perfect can be used in the third sentence, not the past perfect.

Answer (score 1):

Although I'm not a native speaker, here's my take:

A) Yes, both can be used. If you choose Present Perfect, you're talking about an experience you had in your life - that's it. If you choose Past Perfect, you're also talking about an experience in your life, but with a specific moment in time (in the past).

B) No, Present Perfect can't be used in this case, because (as said in (A)) you're mentioning a specific moment in the past.

Comment: The PP implies a previous event that occurred at a specific  time that would take the SP. The third sentence is fine.

Comment: PP - Present Perfect, or PP - Past Perfect?

Comment: The Past Perfect etc.

Comment: Yes, but it is clear from the context that the point in time is now.

Comment: I am sorry, but I am confused

Answer (score 0):

If you say " I have never experienced a pain like that before", you are speaking from the present. You have never felt such a pain before in your life, before this present moment.  If you use "I had never felt such a pain before" you are talking about the pain you felt yesterday, which is now the past and you had never felt such a pain before that past moment yesterday. So, you use present perfect for the now and past perfect for the past. You can't change sentence 3 into present perfect, in my opinion.

Comment: You can if you sort of put yourself in yesterday's shoes, or you're still under the impression that just talking about the event makes it feel like you're experiencing it all over again. Something like the historical present.

Answer (score 0):

This question is very simple, as regards speech:

I have never experienced such a pain before. [Ok,past, non-specific]

or

1) I had never experienced such a pain before.

[Ok in a specific conversation or context, like the one below. **It presupposes a conversation where the simple past event is implied or mentioned**. The event is not provided here by the OP.)]

**There is no rule that states you can't use the past perfect as the sole verb.** **However, when it is the sole verb, it implies some other event occurred before it. And the speakers are aware of it OR the event is mentioned earlier in a written text.**

2) I **had a** terrible pain yesterday. I **had never experienced** anything like that before.

Remember the timeline, taken from the website of Tony Hartley.
http://tonyeosenglish.weebly.com/

[image: Tony Hartley's]